# Word 2010 ribbon tab cycling

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, hotkeys, ribbon

Is there a hotkey (or possibility to set one) for tabbing through those ribbon tabs (Home, Insert, etc) in Word 2010?

By "tabbing through" I mean similar to the behavior of  cycling through open tabs in Chrome or Safari with Ctrl-tab.

[image]

Comment: Not a 'hotkey', but you can (also) use you mouse-wheel to change tabs while the pointer is hovering over the ribbon.

Answer (score 2):

Push the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and the shortcuts will show up. To cycle through, use the left and right arrow keys.

Comment: To cycle through groups on the same tab (e.g. Font, Paragraph, Styles), use Alt and then Ctrl+Arrow.